# VS Code IntelliSense enabled when developing inside a Docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, npm, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm wondering whether it is possible to have VS Code IntelliSense enabled when developing inside a Docker container where all the dependencies are locally installed?

Comment: Im wondering have you found an answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install node\_modules inside Docker container and synchronize them with host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097652/install-node-modules-inside-docker-container-and-synchronize-them-with-host)

Answer (score 8):

VS Code has recently launched its [Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers):

> The Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension lets you use a Docker container as a full-featured development environment. It allows you to open any folder inside (or mounted into) a container and take advantage of Visual Studio Code's full feature set.

But most importantly for your use case:

> This lets VS Code provide a local-quality development experience — including full IntelliSense (completions), code navigation, and debugging — regardless of where your tools (or code) are located.

I made a screencast that shows that:

1. The project is mounted inside a Docker container via VS Code itself
2. An npm package [ramda.js](/questions/tagged/ramda.js) is installed from the running container
3. VS Code IntelliSense is able to make suggestions even though the package was installed in the container.

Here's the relevant configuration file `.devcontainer.json` at the root of the project:

```
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "image": "node:12-alpine"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having mixed results with this. Does your container mount `node_modules` as a volume? If you expand `node_modules` in the VScode explorer, are the subfolders visible?

Comment: @defraggled VS Code automatically mounts the root folder in the container and opens a shell in the container (not on the host) so whatever you do there will be reflected on the host.