# Install node_modules inside Docker container and synchronize them with host

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, node-modules

I have the problem with installing `node_modules` inside the Docker container and synchronize them with the host. My Docker's version is `18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40` and Docker Compose's version is  `1.21.2, build a133471`.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```yaml
# Frontend Container.
frontend:
  build: ./app/frontend
  volumes:
    - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
    - frontend-node-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${ENV}
  command: npm start

# Define all the external volumes.
volumes:
  frontend-node-modules: ~
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# Set the base image.
FROM node:10

# Create and define the working directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install the application's dependencies.
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
```

The trick with the external volume is described in a lot of blog posts and Stack Overflow answers. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds/32785014#32785014).

The application works great. The source code is synchronized. The hot reloading works great too.

The only problem that I have is that `node_modules` folder is empty on the host. Is it possible to synchronize the `node_modules` folder that is inside Docker container with the host?

I've already read these answers:

1. [docker-compose volume on node_modules but is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425996/docker-compose-volume-on-node-modules-but-is-empty)
2. [Accessing node_modules after npm install inside Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245831/accessing-node-modules-after-npm-install-inside-docker)

Unfortunately, they didn't help me a lot. I don't like [the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728476/4815056), because I don't want to run `npm install` on my host because of the possible cross-platform issues (e.g. the host is Windows or Mac and the Docker container is Debian 8 or Ubuntu 16.04). [The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36246223/4815056) is not good for me too, because I'd like to run `npm install` in my `Dockerfile` instead of running it after the Docker container is started.

Also, I've found [this blog post](https://blog.sergeyev.info/docker-development-environment/). The author tries to solve the same problem I am faced with. The problem is that `node_modules` won't be synchronized because we're just copying them from the Docker container to the host.

I'd like my `node_modules` inside the Docker container to be synchronized with the host. Please, take into account that I want:

- to install `node_modules` automatically instead of manually
- to install `node_modules` inside the Docker container instead of the host
- to have `node_modules` synchronized with the host (if I install some new package inside the Docker container, it should be synchronized with the host automatically without any manual actions)

I need to have `node_modules` on the host, because:

- possibility to read the source code when I need
- the IDE needs `node_modules` to be installed locally so that it could have access to the `devDependencies` such as `eslint` or `prettier`. I don't want to install these `devDependencies` globally.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

At first, I would like to thank [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) and [trust512](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425640/trust512) for posting their answers. Unfortunately, they didn't help me to solve my problem.

I would like to post my answer to this question.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
# Define Docker Compose version.
version: "3"

# Define all the containers.
services:
  # Frontend Container.
  frontend:
    build: ./app/frontend
    volumes:
      - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    command: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# Set the base image.
FROM node:10

# Create and define the node_modules's cache directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache
WORKDIR /usr/src/cache

# Install the application's dependencies into the node_modules's cache directory.
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# Create and define the application's working directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

And last but not least `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -r /usr/src/cache/node_modules/. /usr/src/app/node_modules/
exec npm start
```

The trickiest part here is to install the `node_modules` into the `node_module`'s cache directory (`/usr/src/cache`) which is defined in our `Dockerfile`. After that, `entrypoint.sh` will move the `node_modules` from the cache directory (`/usr/src/cache`) to our application directory (`/usr/src/app`). Thanks to this the entire `node_modules` directory will appear on our host machine.

Looking at my question above I wanted:

> - to install `node_modules` automatically instead of manually
> - to install `node_modules` inside the Docker container instead of the host
> - to have `node_modules` synchronized with the host (if I install some new package inside the Docker container, it should be
>   synchronized with the host automatically without any manual actions

The first thing is done: `node_modules` are installed automatically. The second thing is done too: `node_modules` are installed inside the Docker container (so, there will be no cross-platform issues). And the third thing is done too: `node_modules` that were installed inside the Docker container will be **visible** on our host machine and they will be **synchronized**! If we install some new package inside the Docker container, it will be synchronized with our host machine at once.

The important thing to note: truly speaking, the new package installed inside the Docker container, will appear in `/usr/src/app/node_modules`. As this directory is synchronized with our host machine, this new package will appear on our host machine's `node_modules` directory too. But the `/usr/src/cache/node_modules` will have the old build at this point (without this new package). Anyway, it is not a problem for us. During next `docker-compose up --build` (`--build` is required) the Docker will re-install the `node_modules` (because `package.json` was changed) and the `entrypoint.sh` file will move them to our `/usr/src/app/node_modules`.

You should take into account one more important thing. If you `git pull` the code from the remote repository or `git checkout your-teammate-branch` when Docker is running, there may be some new packages added to the `package.json` file. In this case, you should stop the Docker with `CTRL + C` and up it again with `docker-compose up --build` (`--build` is required). If your containers are running as a daemon, you should just execute `docker-compose stop` to stop the containers and up it again with `docker-compose up --build` (`--build` is required).

If you have any questions, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Using rsync instead of cp can save time. The command runs almost instantly if you already have copied node_modules previously. For example, in my script I run:
`rsync -arv /home/app/node_modules /tmp/node_modules`

Comment: This is brilliant but how does one use this when running it in a jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Is there any official thing for this "problem" ?
I'm looking for a clean approach where leave all the work for container, and have some sync mechanism from container to host to be able to use prettier, git, eslint from local(host).

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea bout how to speed up the process? Using `rsync` reduces the time of following container runs, but increases the time of the first run after every image build.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh', Can anyone help me?

Comment: Forget it. I had to convert the `entrypoint.sh` to unix format.

Comment: hi I tried ur solution, I got `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 8: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: not found`.

Comment: Thank you this worked well for me! Small note, since I hadn't generated a `package-lock.json` yet, this generated an error during the build. Instead of having 2 separate lines in the `Dockerfile` for copying `package-lock.json` and `package.json`, it's easy to use one line with `COPY package*.json ./` which covers both or either.

Comment: i got this error
`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 8: exec: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: Permission denied` any fix?

Comment: `RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache` is unnecessary since  `WORKDIR /usr/src/cache` creates the desired directory

Comment: @saadi i got the same issue, how did you solve it?

Comment: Comment from @JosephSiefers is a good one -- rsync vs cp in the entrypoint file speeds things dramatically.  I needed to add rsync to the base image we're using (node-18.19-slim) using `apt-get`.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 22):

Having run into this issue and finding the accepted answer pretty slow to copy all `node_modules` to the host in every container run, I managed to solve it by installing the dependencies in the container, mirror the host volume, and skip installing again if a `node_modules` folder is present:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD [ -d "node_modules" ] && npm run start || npm ci && npm run start
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  service-1:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
```

When you need to reinstall the dependencies just delete `node_modules`.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I've seen yet and doesn't require extra entry-point scripts. On first run, I see that a node_modules folder gets created on my local file system.

Comment: How does this even work, the node_modules folder from the Dockerfile gets overwritten when mounting the volume.

Comment: @DanielW. I had the same first impression, but it probably works because CMD is executed when container starts (after mounting the volume)

Comment: please explain what this command does: CMD [ -d "node_modules" ]

Comment: @БектурМуратов It checks if a directory named "node_modules" exists

Comment: Most elegant solution I've seen Just escape `\[` `\]` special characters for CMD line  like this: `CMD \[ -d "node_modules" \] && npm run start || npm ci && npm run start`

Answer (score 14):

### A Simple, Complete Solution

You can install node_modules in the container using the external named volume trick **and** synchronize it with the host by configuring the volume's storage location to point to your host's node_modules directory. This can be done with a named [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) using the [local driver](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts) and a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), as seen in the example below.

The volume's data is stored on your host anyway, in something like /var/lib/docker/volumes/, so we're just storing it inside your project instead.

To do this in Docker Compose, just add your node_modules volume to your front-end service, and then configure the volume in the named volumes section, where "device" is the **relative path** (from the location of docker-compose.yml) to your local (host) node_modules directory.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  ui:
    # Your service options...
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/path/to/node_modules

volumes:
  node_modules:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./local/path/to/node_modules
```

The key with this solution is to never make changes directly in your host node_modules, but always install, update, or remove Node packages in the container.

**Version Control Tip:**
When your Node package.json/package-lock.json files change, either when pulling, or switching branches, in addition to rebuilding the Image, you have to remove the Volume, and delete its contents:

```
docker volume rm example_node_modules
rm -rf local/path/to/node_modules
mkdir local/path/to/node_modules
```

**Documentation:**

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts

Comment: This solution looks cool. Could you please explain the volumes part ? Thank you!

Comment: @madhan in volumes it's creating a named volume called node_modules using the local driver with a bind mount, and the most important part, the "device" is the location where the volume data is stored. You can read more about volumes and bind mounts using the links above under Documentation.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to create a folder at run time if its does not exists in `device` ?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. In case my it is at root level `./node_modules` and docker didn't create it automatically. I have create it manually and rest all goes smooth. I'll try to find a way.

Answer (score 10):

There's three things going on here:

1. When you run `docker build` or `docker-compose build`, your Dockerfile builds a new image containing a `/usr/src/app/node_modules` directory and a Node installation, but nothing else.  In particular, your application isn't in the built image.
2. When you `docker-compose up`, the `volumes: ['./app/frontend:/usr/src/app']` directive hides whatever was in `/usr/src/app` and mounts host system content on top of it.
3. Then the `volumes: ['frontend-node-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules']` directive mounts the named volume on top of the `node_modules` tree, hiding the corresponding host system directory.

If you were to launch another container and attach the named volume to it, I expect you'd see the `node_modules` tree there.  For what you're describing you just don't want the named volume: delete the second line from the `volumes:` block and the `volumes:` section at the end of the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have removed those two lines. After that, I have the same issue which was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds/). When I am running `docker-compose up`, the `node_modules` that were installed in the Docker container with `docker-compose build`, are overridden by the application's source code (`./app/frontend:/usr/src/app`). I don't have `node_modules` on the host and because of this, I'm getting an error inside the container (e.i. `node_modules` don't exist).

Comment: Yes, that's correct, that is in fact how it works: the mounted volume / host directory hides what was in the image.  Docker won't automatically copy things from an image to a host-path volume ever.  You could run `npm install` or `yarn install` on your host directory before launching the container, or change your command to something like `npm install && npm start`.

Comment: I got it. The problem is that I wouldn't like to run `npm install` on my host machine because of the possible cross-platform issues. `node_modules` installed on the host machine don't always work properly inside the Docker container. There could be a lot of problems such as different environments, different `NPM` or `Node.js` versions (e.g. we run `npm install` on Mac with `Node.js 8.11.3` and `NPM 5.6.0` and mount the volume to the Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container with `Node.js 10.5.0` and `NPM 6.1.0`). The application won't work. As I understand, it is not possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: For example, [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) is a binary and it really matters where it was compiled. If the environments differ, we will get an error. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942769/issue-to-node-sass-and-docker).

Answer (score 6):

No one has mentioned solution with actually using docker's `entrypoint` feature.

Here is my working solution:

Dockerfile (multistage build, so it is both production and local dev ready):

```
FROM node:10.15.3 as production
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && npm install --only=dev

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]


FROM production as dev

COPY docker/dev-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["dev-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "watch"]
```

docker/dev-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

npm install && npm install --only=dev ## Note this line, rest is copy+paste from original entrypoint

if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ]; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    web:
        build:
            target: dev
            context: .
        volumes:
            - .:/app:delegated
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        restart: always
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: dev
```

With this approach you achieve all 3 points you required and imho it is much cleaner way - not need to move files around.

Comment: Could you please clarify why this works? Specifically, I am unsure how it makes the `node_modules` directory available to the host through the mounted volume.

Comment: Sure! The thing is that ENTRYPOINT part (the command) in terms of container's lifecycle is called AFTER volume is mounted on already running container, so any changes made to the filesystem done in it will be reflected to the host - in fact `node_modules` directory at this point is host's directory and not the one built during `docker build` directly on the image.

Comment: This approach doesn't worked for me. When resolving packages with yarn, it stuck for long time.

Comment: This worked and out of all the other answers, this one is preferable for all the reasons the author said.

Comment: I believe this is functionally the same as what @lewislbr did. ENTRYPOINT and CMD happen at the same stage (container built, volume mounted) and the action is the same: `npm install`.

Answer (score 4):

Binding your host node_modules folder with your container node_modules is not a good practice as you mention. I have seen the solution of creating an internal volume for this folder quite often. Not doing so will cause problems during the building stage.

I ran into this problem when I was trying to build a docker development environment for an angular app, that shows tslib errors when I was editing the files within my host folder cause my host's node_modules folder was empty (as expected).

The cheap solution that helps me, in this case, was to use the Visual Studio Code Extension called **"Remote-Containers"**.

This extension will allow you to attach your **Visual Studio Code** to your container and edit transparently your files within your container folders. To do so, it will install an internal vscode server within your development container. For more information check [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers).

Ensure, however, that your volumes are still created in your docker-compose.yml file.

I hope it helps :D!

Comment: The only issue I have with this is the console logs. As the container has to be launched from the host, the terminal on the host is the one showing the output of my CMD command (`ng serve` in my case). When attaching to the container in VSCode, I lose that output. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

My workaround is to install dependencies when the container is starting instead of during build-time.

#### Dockerfile:

```
# We're using a multi-stage build so that we can install dependencies during build-time only for production.

# dev-stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS dev-stage
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY . .
# `yarn install` will run every time we start the container. We're using yarn because it's much faster than npm when there's nothing new to install
CMD ["sh", "-c", "yarn install && yarn run start"]

# production-stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS production-stage
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
```

#### .dockerignore

Add `node_modules` to `.dockerignore` to prevent it from being copied when the `Dockerfile` runs `COPY . .`. We use volumes to bring in `node_modules`.

```
**/node_modules
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
node_app:
    container_name: node_app
    build:
        context: ./node_app
        target: dev-stage # `production-stage` for production
    volumes:
        # For development:
        #   If node_modules already exists on the host, they will be copied
        #   into the container here. Since `yarn install` runs after the
        #   container starts, this volume won't override the node_modules.
        - ./node_app:/usr/src/app
        # For production:
        #   
        - ./node_app:/usr/src/app
        - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Comment: To me this is the best answer as it avoids the need to rebuild the image when changing the dependencies, which is more efficient for local dev, and it's really simple.

Comment: Note that for the dev image the line `COPY package.json ./` is useless as it is immediately followed by `COPY . .`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest overlapping volumes, although I haven't seen any official docs ban it, I've had some issues with it in the past. How I do it is:

1. Get rid of the external volume as you are not planning on actually using it how it's meant to be used - respawning the container with its data created specifically in the container after stopping+removing it.

The above might be achieved by shortening your compose file a bit:

```
frontend:
  build: ./app/frontend
  volumes:
    - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${ENV}
  command: npm start
```

2. Avoid overlapping volume data with Dockerfile instructions when not necessary.

That means you might need two Dockerfiles - one for local development and one for deploying a fat image with all the application dist files layered inside.

That said, consider a development Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
```

The above makes the application create a full node_modules installation and map it to your host location, while the docker-compose specified command would start your application off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like I will have the same problem as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097652/install-node-modules-inside-docker-container-and-synchronize-them-with-host#comment89188358_51099162), won't I?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand why you want your source code to live inside the container **and** host **and** bind mount each others during development. Usually, you want your source code to live inside the container for deployments, not development since the code is available on your host and bind mounted.

Your `docker-compose.yml`

```
frontend:
  volumes:
    - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
```

Your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Of course you must run `npm install` first time and everytime package.json changes, but you run it inside the container so there is no cross-platform issue: `docker-compose exec frontend npm install`

Finally start your server `docker-compose exec frontend npm start`

And then later, usually in a CI pipeline targetting a deployment, you build your final image with the whole source code copied and node_modules reinstalled, but of course at this point you don't need anymore the bind mount and "synchronization", so your setup could look like :

`docker-compose.yml`

```
frontend:
  build:
    context: ./app/frontend
    target: dev
  volumes:
    - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10 as dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

FROM dev as build

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And you target the build stage of your Dockerfile later, either manually or during a pipeline, to build your deployment-ready image.

I know it's not the exact answer to your questions since you have to run npm install and nothing lives inside the container during development, but it solves your node_modules issue, and I feel like your questions are mixing development and deployment considerations, so maybe you thought about this problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

The best for development

### docker-compose.yml

```
...
  frontend:
    build: ./app/frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./app/frontend:/usr/src/app
...
```

### ./app/frontend/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g react-scripts

RUN chown -Rh node:node /usr/src/app

USER node

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run start" ]

#FOR PROD
# CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run build" ]
```

The user `node` will help you with the rights of host<->guest

The folder `node_modules` will be accessible from the host and synchronize host<->guest

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Vladyslav Turak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815056/vladyslav-turak) for answer with `entrypoint.sh` where we copy `node_modules` from container to host.

I implemented the similar thing but I run into the issue with husky, @commitlint, tslint npm packages.
I can't push anything into repository.
Reason: I copied `node_modules` from Linux to Windows. In my case <5% of files are different (.bin and most of package.json) and 95% are the same. [example: image with diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyw2j.png)

So I returned to solution with `npm install` of `node_modules` for Windows first (for IDE and debugging). And Docker image will contain Linux version of `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this was resolved, but what about:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Your other staffs

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    api:
        build: ./path/to/folder/with/a/dockerfile
        volumes:
            - "./volumes/app:/usr/src/app"
        command: "npm start"
```

volumes/app/package.json

```
{
    ... ,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm install && node server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ....
    }
 }
```

After run, node_modules will be present in your volumes, but its contents are generated within the container so no cross platform problems.

Comment: @Vladyslav Turak can you please clear my confusion for entrypoint.sh which one is container path and system path for copying node_module dir

Comment: Any idea about avoiding reinstalling on every container run?

Comment: @lewislbr there is no harm with running "npm install" on every container run. It won't re-install anything already installed because the node_modules will persist between runs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `dockerized npm install`. This is the same as `npm install` but it runs on a docker container.

- https://github.com/datastack-net/dockerized

The node_modules will be written to the host. It should work out of the box and you can specify which npm version to use. If needed, the container can be extended or customized.

Be aware that some npm packages may require compilation, and the generated binaries may not be compatible with your host machine. If you just need the source code or dist files, this is not an issue.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Dockerized.